# Append figure with new plots

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to visualize two sets of data in different figures. Here is how do I realize it now:

```
f1 = figure;
for i=0:6
    plot(stim(i)+i);
    hold on;
end;

f2 = figure;
for i=0:6
    plot(data(i)+i);
    hold on;
end;
```

I think there have to be the way to combine these loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. As per [Matlab reference](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure.html): first you create empty figures and do the `hold-on` (you don't need to do it every time):

```
f1 = figure;
hold on
f2 = figure;
hold on
```

Then you loop:

```
for i=0:6
    figure(f1)
    plot(stim(i)+i);
    figure(f2)
    plot(data(i)+i);
end
```

This time the figures are already created; calling `figure` here therefore switches the active figure so you can plot on it;

Answer (score 0):

And without for loops, something like this:

```
idx = (0:6).';
figure(f1);
plot(stim(idx)+idx);
figure(f2);
plot(data(idx)+idx);
```

Make sure that you apply the solution to the right dimension. The column vectors are interpreted as one dataset; And for points, remember to set the markers.